# Magento theme page

Tags: magento, themes, skin

This is my first time working with Magento so this might be a n00b question.

i've set up 2 store views NL & UK. Both have the same theme.
It all works fine in my UK store. But when I go to contact or to one of the checkout pages in the dutch version the theme disappears.

NL version
/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css

UK version
/skin/frontend/default/theme375/css/styles.css

How do I get the dutch version to work the same as the UK one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System > Configuration > Design > Theme - note that you may need to change the Configuration Scope to view settings for the Dutch/UK websites/stores. It's best to set settings as "high up" as possible.